# How to get aggregate count with date attribute via linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, linq, group-by

I have a table of data where I'm recording hits on a website. The table tracks the timestamp of the hit as well as the source. I want to pull hits per day, with the counts categorized by the source. So the result would be something like

```
{
    google: {
        { 01/01/2000, 123 }, // date, count of hits for that date
        { 01/02/2000, 134 },
        { 01/03/2000, 223 },
        { 01/04/2000, 145 },
    },
    yahoo: {
        { 01/01/2000, 223 },
        { 01/02/2000, 434 },
        { 01/03/2000, 123 },
        { 01/04/2000, 135 },
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get this data aggregated in this format using linq? At the moment I can get the aggregate totals of the source / count using

```
var counts = tableName.GroupBy(x => x.ColumnId)
                  .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

but adding the additional date attribute is eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform grouping again by date:

```cs
var counts = tableName
    .GroupBy(x => x.ColumnId)
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        Category = g.Key, 
        Items = g.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Date)
            .Select(x => new 
            {
                Date = x.Key,
                Count = x.Count()
            })
            .ToList()
    });
```